# Sitecore Language wise css changes

Tags: css

We are working on Sitecore "Arabic" and "English" languages. As you know Arabic start from right to left and English start left to right. Due to this reason we have to write two class for same element div,button,form etc.. For example "Arabic Header" and "English Header".

How to maintain this in Sitecore?

Should i have to create Asset folder with two sub folder "En" and "Ar" and then render by current context language?

Should i have to include all css in media library and render base on that?

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 4):

Better to add class to `body` tag:

```
<body class="ar">
```

In code it will be look like:

```
<body class="@Html.Sitecore().GetBodyCssClass()">


        public static HtmlString GetBodyCssClass(this SitecoreHelper helper)
        {
            var cssClass = string.Empty;
            if (Context.Language != null && Context.Language.CultureInfo != null)
            {
                cssClass = Context.Language.CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToLower();
                if (Context.Language.CultureInfo.Name.ToLower() != cssClass)
                {
                    cssClass += " " + Context.Language.CultureInfo.Name.ToLower();
                }
            }

            return new HtmlString(cssClass);
        }
```

Also you need to have one css file with defined styles like:

```
body.ar .main-slider {
    left: auto;
    right: 50px
}
```

It means that you need to have separate styles for `ar` language (LeftToRight styles). You can use [ASP.NET Bundles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) for join your all css files.